# Text View in List to send multiple sms android studio

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, smsmanager

I want to be able to send an emergency sms to any amount of phone numbers in a list. I have most of it done, but I can't figure out how to make the string (phone) to send to all the numbers in the list. Currently it only sends to the very last number. I've got a fragment where you put the numbers into the list, I use sharedpreferences to send the details across and then from another fragment, you press the button and it is meant to send the sms. But I don't know how many numbers there could be in the list.

I also want it to send the number every 10 minutes, but I'll work on that after the fact.

Thanks in advance.

```
 case R.id.settings_my_health_alert_help_button:
            String phone = sharedpreferences.getString("phone", "");
            if (phone.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No emergency contact added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                //send sms
                sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, "Emergency At: " + address, null, null);
            }
```

**EDIT: I thought I'd give you more info, as I probably should in the first place:** this is where the contacts are put into a list view.

```
public class ContactsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final int CONTACT_LOADER = 0;

private View addContactView;
private ListView contactsList;

private CursorAdapter contactAdapter;
private CursorLoader loader;
private Cursor cursor;

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting_my_health_contacts_list);

    addContactView = findViewById(R.id.settings_my_health_pills_rem_add);
    contactsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settings_my_health_pills_list);

    addContactView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER, null, this);
}

private void updateSettings(){
    contactAdapter = new CursorAdapter(this, cursor, true){
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View view = View.inflate(ContactsActivity.this, R.layout.settings_my_health_contact_item, null);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_name);
            TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_phone);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_name);
            TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_phone);


            Contact contact = Contact.fromCursor(cursor);

            name.setText(contact.getName());
            phone.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
            setLongClickListener(view, contact);
        }

        public void setLongClickListener(final View view, final Contact contact){
            view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    DialogsHelper.getOKCancelDialog(ContactsActivity.this, "Would you like delete contact " + contact.getName() + "?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            String selection = MezzoSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID +  "=?";
                            String[] args = { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) };
                            getContentResolver().delete(MezzoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_CONTACTS,
                                    selection, args);
                        }
                    }, null);
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }
    };
    contactsList.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.settings_my_health_pills_rem_add:
            final AddContactDialog dialog = new AddContactDialog(this, new EditDialogCallback<DoubleEditTextDialog.DoubleEditTextView>() {
                @Override
                public void onOkClick(DoubleEditTextDialog.DoubleEditTextView editForm) {
                    String name = editForm.getEditText1();
                    String phone = editForm.getEditText2();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("name", name);
                    editor.putString("phone", phone);

                    editor.commit();

                    Contact contact = new Contact(name, phone);
                    getContentResolver().insert(MezzoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_CONTACTS, contact.buildContentValues());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCanceled() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onInit(DoubleEditTextDialog.DoubleEditTextView editForm) {

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is `phone` the list of phone numbers? Is it comma delimited?

Comment: phone is the list of phone numbers that could be added - could be 1, or it could be 10, and no, it's not delimited.

Answer (score 0):

Add your phone numbers in a array list and pass to next activity

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("phone", list);
```

To get data

```
 ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("phone");
```

**OR**

send phone number as string space delimted or comma delimited

```
String phone="*************,*************,**********";
```

Use the java split method

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
String[] numbers=phone.split(",");
for(String s:numbers){
   //send sms
}
```

To get the data from fragment

```
ArrayList<String> myList =(ArrayList<String>)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("phone");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Exbury. My code says it can't resolve 'intent'.

Comment: Does it make a difference if it goes from an Activity to a fragment? It just says Cannot resolve symbol 'intent'. It says it on both the Activity where the phone numbers are created and where I try to call them.

Comment: getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");

Comment: getActivity() in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated

Comment: Hi Exbury, I've added the Contacts Activity above for you to have a look, cos even tho I added the getActivity part, it doesn't seem to like it at all. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: are u currently getting any errors or working but getting single phone number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65742/discussion-between-kozbot-and-exbury).